# route doesn't work at production environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have created following route

```
 routes.MapRoute("ThumbnailRoute",// Route name
           "Image/{action}/{session}/{parentId}/{fileName}/{ctype}/{thumbNailSize}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Image", action = "GenerateThumbnail", session = "", parentId = "", fileName = "", ctype = "", thumbNailSize = 70 },  // Parameter defaults 
           new { controller = @"[^\.]*", action = @"[^\.]*" });
```

and my extension method returns a string like following which will be the src attribute of the img tag:

```
 return string.Format("/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}/{5}/{6}", controller, action, session, parentId, fileName, ctype, thumbNailSize);
```

when I right click on the pages and choose properties for both dev and prod environments the src av img tag is same (http://localhost/Image/GenerateThumbnail/de-DE/121/0beac6da-7c09-4faf-ad4b-48326f9d337e.jpg/jpeg/70) only different is the domain name (localhost, www.domain.com) but the images de not appear on prod. thanks for your help

Comment: Good Lord! Is this a real route? You got six slashes over there!

Comment: what response do you get? error?

Answer (score 0):

If the URLs look fine on the production version - perhaps the issue isn't with the routing, but rather with the code in the action method.

Have you checked what response you get from the browser when hitting the production URL?

What response do you get when your browse to http://www.domain.com/Image/GenerateThumbnail/de-DE/121/0beac6da-7c09-4faf-ad4b-48326f9d337e.jpg/jpeg/70?

Comment: when I browse to the image, it generates error:A generic error occurred in GDI+. System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) +439618
   System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageFormat format) +36
.....

Comment: so the error is probably nothing to do with routing, but is an error saving the image. At a guess, given it works locally but not on your server and the error is in saving the image, it's probably a permission issue.

Comment: but I dont save the thumbnails, the exception occurred at line 62 in ExecuteResult method of ThumbnailActionResult and the line 62 is targetBmp.Save(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png); and the Action which is called returns a ThumbnailActionResult (response). so I don't save images at all

Comment: try googling your actual error message.  I found a stack overflow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003962/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-error-while-showing-uploaded-images) which looks like it might be related

Comment: I want to know that the problem solved when i changed ImageFormat.png to Jpeg in mybitmap.Save(stream, Imageformat.png);
thank you all which spend your time on this issue

Answer (score 0):

Never hardcode urls as you did. Always use url helpers. The thing is that when you deploy your application in IIS there's a virtual directory name. So the correct url is the following:

```
http://foo.com/MyAppName/Image/GenerateThumbnail/de-DE/121/0beac6da-7c09-4faf-ad4b-48326f9d337e.jpg/jpeg/70
```

instead of:

```
http://foo.com/Image/GenerateThumbnail/de-DE/121/0beac6da-7c09-4faf-ad4b-48326f9d337e.jpg/jpeg/70
```

Since you have hardcoded the url you get 404.

So use the [RouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505215.aspx) method to generate it which will take into account this virtual directory if any. Don't use any string formatting to build urls:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string url = Url.RouteUrl("ThumbnailRoute", new
    {
        action = "GenerateThumbnail",
        controller = "Image",
        session = session,
        parentId = parentId,
        fileName = fileName,
        ctype = ctype,
        thumbNailSize = thumbNailSize
    });

    ...
}
```

Comment: hi, I changed what you said, but still get same error, I think the problem is something about the life of the the image, because I dont save it, but using a ActionResult to return the data.

Comment: Yes, there could be bugs in your controller action that is supposed to serve the image. For example some exception could be thrown and you might be returning a 404. At least with my code this action will be invoked, whereas with your hardcoded not and the 404 will be returned immediately without even reaching your action.

Comment: I want to know that the problem solved when i changed ImageFormat.png to Jpeg in mybitmap.Save(stream, Imageformat.png);